# Can outlook mail that is permanently deleted from my personal laptop and home wifi be traceable by mail monitoring software?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am working in MNC. Used the mail id provided by client while creating account in Kik app, by mistake.Received automatic account confirmation mail from Kik. I deleted the mail permanently (ie from inbox, then deleted items and then recovery items folders in outlook web version in 15 minutes time) using my personal laptop and home Wifi. I am scared whether client IT team can find this using any mail monitoring software. Please post your suggestions.

Comment: I suppose, in an enterprise scenario, they DO have access to your mailbox, but theres no telling whether they have a hidden mail backup scheme going on, or if they can recover data from your mailbox. Since you've deleted it permanently, they would have to go out of their way to actually recover it, and even if they do, its only Kik - nothing illegal or against the company

Comment: @QuickishFM Thanks for your clarification. Very useful. Also ,  I deactivated that kik account sooner. Thanks again.

Comment: @QuickishFM Your comment is really an answer and should be posted as an answer.

Comment: I will add as so and provide more information

Answer (score 0):

If the mail account was provided by the client, then yes, it is entirely possible for them to have a record of this in their logging and management systems.

It does't really matter what you do on the client end. Everything depends on the sort of monitoring and reporting they have set up on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

In an enterprise scenario (where they have their own mail servers and you simply have an account with them) they can absolutely access your mailbox, and may even have a hidden mail backup scheme in place to clone emails, despite how quickly you delete it. Having said that, an email for Kik is hardly anything to worry about, and if you've permanently deleted it, they would have to go out of their way to recover it, and that's assuming they

- have an email cloning or hidden recycle bin scheme in place,
- actually care about a Kik email.

In the case of something illegal or even against policy, or if they are asked to silently record communication by law enforcement (for example) then they could copy all of your emails for an indefinite time. However, it seems you are just worried about them finding out you use Kik - that really is nothing to worry about. For your own information, even the IT guy who has automated 99% of his job has better things to do than snoop around :)